# My Paw "environment variable"s are missing from the "manage" dialog, but still available to requests

Tags: paw-app

My Paw "environment variable"s are missing from the "manage" dialog:

[image: "Manage" dialog]

.. but still available to requests:

[image: Available to the request]

Docs: https://paw.cloud/docs/environments/environments-reusable-presets

Comment: Sorry for having missed this thread. I confirm that we've fixed many issues with the Environment Editor in newer versions of Paw. Do you still have issues with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions of the Manage dialog had been collapsed for some reason. Once I dragged it bigger using the lower righthand corner, I could see the variables.